# componente hijo no funciona en angularjs con ui router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

No puedo hacer funcionar esto y la informacion en internet no me es clara ni suficiente, si me funciona $parent pero esto otro no me funciona.

state

```
.state('/agregar_cotizacion/:id', {
            url: '/agregar_cotizacion/:id',
            templateUrl: 'assets/tpl/cotizaciones/agregar.html',
            controller: "cotizacion as coti",
            resolve: {
                factory: checkRouting
            }
        })
```

html padre

```
    <div>
        <autorizacion-temporal
        hola="coti.hola"></autorizacion-temporal>
    </div>
```

html hijo (autorizacion-temporal.html)

```
<span>
   hola {{$coti.hola.nombre}} 
</span>
```

js padre

```
function cotizacion($scope, $state) {
    var thes = this;
    thes.hola = {
        nombre: "wilb padre"
    }
};
```

js hijo

```
function autorizacionTemporal_ctr($scope) {

}
angular.module('app')
  .component("autorizacionTemporal", {
    templateUrl: "./assets/tpl/componentes/autorizacion-temporal/dialogo.html",
    controller: autorizacionTemporal_ctr,
    bindings: {
      hola: "="
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

La solucion esta en que el componente hijo es el que lleva el

> controllerAS:

state:

```
.state('/agregar_cotizacion/:id', {
            url: '/agregar_cotizacion/:id',
            templateUrl: 'assets/tpl/cotizaciones/agregar.html',
            controller: cotizacion,
            resolve: {
                factory: checkRouting
            }
        })
```

html padre:

```
        <autorizacion-temporal 
            hola="hola">
        </autorizacion-temporal>
```

js controller padre:

```
$scope.hola = {
        nombre: "hola"
    }
```

El "controllerAs" es en el componente hijo:

```
function autorizacionTemporal_ctr($scope) {
this.hola.nombre = "saludo del padre modificado";
}
angular.module('app')
  .component("autorizacionTemporal", {
    templateUrl: "./assets/tpl/componentes/autorizacion-temporal/dialogo.html",
    controller: autorizacionTemporal_ctr,
    controllerAs: "auto",
    bindings: {
    hola: "="
    }
  });
```

y el html hijo seria:

```
<span>
   hijo: {{auto.hola.nombre}}
</span>
```